# Django: How to change the model field display in admin site

Tags: django

I hope the title is enough to know what my problem.

i have this code in my models

```
Courses = models.ForeignKey(Course,  on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

and this what it looks like in admin site

[image]

How do i change the display field name in my admin site, **Course** to **Track** without changing the field name in my models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Courses = models.ForeignKey(Course,  on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Track")
```